# Bloons TD 6 Upgrade Paths

Tags: code-golf, number, kolmogorov-complexity

## Background

The monkeys need help organizing their defense and have asked you, [Benjamin](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Benjamin_(BTD6)) the code monkey, to create a program that will list all tower upgrade options. Each tower has three unique upgrade "paths", each having a tier represented by a number between 0 and 5 inclusive, 0 meaning no upgrade. Up to two paths may be chosen for upgrading, that is contain an upgrade tier 1 or greater. Additionally, only one path can can contain a tier 3 or greater.

## Task

Output in some reasonable format all valid upgrade path triples in *any order* (the triples themselves are ordered). Triples can be represented in any reasonable way, such as 025 or 0-2-5. The triples must be distinguishable from each other in some way, so a flat list of numbers without triple delimiters is not allowed.

Here is an example list of all 64 possible triples, as they appear in-game for your insta-monkey collection:

```
5-2-0
5-0-2
5-1-0
5-0-1
5-0-0
2-5-0
0-5-2
1-5-0
0-5-1
0-5-0
2-0-5
0-2-5
1-0-5
0-1-5
0-0-5
4-2-0
4-0-2
4-1-0
4-0-1
4-0-0
2-4-0
0-4-2
1-4-0
0-4-1
0-4-0
2-0-4
0-2-4
1-0-4
0-1-4
0-0-4
3-2-0
3-0-2
3-1-0
3-0-1
3-0-0
2-3-0
0-3-2
1-3-0
0-3-1
0-3-0
2-0-3
0-2-3
1-0-3
0-1-3
0-0-3
2-2-0
2-0-2
2-1-0
2-0-1
2-0-0
0-2-2
1-2-0
0-2-1
0-2-0
1-0-2
0-1-2
0-0-2
1-1-0
1-0-1
1-0-0
0-1-1
0-1-0
0-0-1
0-0-0
```

Comment: Are we allowed to output duplicates? (assuming no)

Comment: @thejonymyster no, there should be exactly 64 triples

Answer (score 6):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
?,/+'!'1|3*<'+!3#3
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJyz19HXVldUN6wx1rJR11Y0Vjbm4tJXcE0syslMLVJILClJzS0oKbYCitlDVJopGCsYOsDU6itUa+kbAoXM7LQrHNRt1CtqlUEyZkAZDbhUhYNNRa26JlwGaFR1hYO+FdSUWiAFNhYipQHlaTrEWMHVAABhOCP+)

`+!3#3` All triples with values in `0 1 2`.
`<'` Grade up each triple. This results in all permutations of `0 1 2` with some duplicates.
`1|3*` Multiply by 3 and take maximum with 1 to generate all permutations of `6 3 1`.
`+'!'` For each permutation, generate all triples where the each entry is a non-negative integer less than the number in the permutation at the same index.
`?,/` Flatten into a matrix with three columns and take the unique rows.

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics`, <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```factor
6 iota 3 selections [ natural-sort "\0"before? ] filter .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy7DsIwDEUHfuSqOxUSEgMMjIiFBTEBgxscsJTGxXEHvj4EMZ9HpOBq9XI@ng5bFH7PnAMXjOSvPug4SKYmSCgoai75@UdqDzZMxu6fySQ7dnUDUSes2yZxcNFccEXrZ6O0/OXobqtFN3BU4z3uiJK8bfpavw)

-1 byte from a tip by @ovs.

Note the string `"\0"` has literal control character `3` embedded as well as the `0`; you can see it on TIO. This string is equivalent to the longer (but clearer) sequence `{ 0 3 }`.

- `6 iota 3 selections`

  Generate all 3-selections of \$[0..5]\$: `{ { 0 0 0 } { 0 0 1 } ... { 5 5 5 } }`
- `[ natural-sort { 0 3 } before? ] filter`

  Select those that when sorted are less than `{ 0 3 }`.
- `.`

  Print them.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>82</s> 80 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
print[k for k in product(*[range(6)]*3)if[0,3]>sorted(k)]
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##DcsxDoAgDADA3Vd0BOJgJHH0I4TBCGiDUFLr4OvR26@9clKde09MBVAiC9F1A5ZGLGZojFVchkQMGbBCYwrPLso43uoR1aK9sRqTm0br1/tPMaisfe8f)

**Explanation:**

- `from itertools import*`: Import `itertools` for the cartesian `product` builtin
- `range(6)`: Push list `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`
- `[^]*3`: Repeat it three times: `[[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,5]]`
- `product(*^)`: Use the cartesian product builtin to get all triplets
- `k for k in ^`: Loop over these triplets
- `^if`: And filter to only keep the triple-tuplets `k` that are:

  - `sorted(k)`: When sorted and converted to an array
  - `[0,3]>^`: are smaller than `[0,3]`
- `[^]`: Wrap all these tuplets into an array
- `print^`: And print it as result

Comment: I think `[0,3]>sorted(k)` is sufficient

Comment: Surely `[range(6]` is roughly equivalent to `[[0,1,2,3,4,5]]`, so that `[range[6]]*3` is `[[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,5]]`?

Comment: @Neil You're right. I've changed the explanation accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 71 bytes

```
for x in range(521):max(s:='%03d'%x)<'6'!=['0','3']>sorted(s)==print(s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY33dPyixQqFDLzFIoS89JTNUyNDDWtchMrNIqtbNVVDYxT1FUrNG3UzdQVbaPVDdR11I3VY-2K84tKUlM0ijVtbQuKMvNKgCyIcVBTYaYDAA)

I took the `['0','3']>sorted(s)` idea from ovs.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/),  <s>75</s>  67 bytes

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)*

Prints one comma-separated triplet per line.

```javascript
for(i=216;i--;)[...a=[i/36%6|0,i/6%6|0,i%6]].sort()<'0,3'&&print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPT1sjQzDpTV9daM1pPTy/RNjpT39hM1azGQCdTH0qrmsXG6hXnF5VoaNqoG@gYq6upFRRl5pVoJGr@/w8A)

Comment: Maybe `for(i=216;i--;)[...a=[i/36%6|0,i/6%6|0,i%6]].sort()<'0,3'&&print(a)`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
uΣmPΠmŀ∫ḣ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v/Tc4tyAcwtyjzY86lj9cMdi4///AQ)

Similar to my K answer.

```
       ∫ḣ3  -- cumulative sums of [1..3] -> [1,3,6]
     mŀ     -- lowered range of each     -> [[0],[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
    Π       -- cartesian product of the three lists
  mP        -- for each triplet, get all permutations
 Σ          -- flatten into a list of triplets
u           -- get the unique ones
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
5Ý3ãʒ{₆1š‹P
```

-2 bytes thanks to a tip of *@ovs* using `136`.

Outputs as a list of triplets.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f9PBc48OLT02qPrY1KvhRw86A//8B)

**Explanation:**

```python
5Ý           # Push a list in the range [0,5]
  3ã         # Cartesian power of 3: get all triplets using these [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    ʒ        # Filter this list by:
     {       #  Sort the triplet from lowest to highest
      ƵZ     #  Push compressed integer 136
        S    #  Convert it to a list of digits: [1,3,6]
         ‹   #  Check for sorted triplet [a,b,c] whether [a<1,b<3,c<6]
          P  #  Check if all three are truthy
             # (after which the filtered list of 64 triplets is output implicitly)
```

`ƵZS` could alternatively be `₆1š` for the same byte-count: [try it online](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9vc2FiaWX//zXDnTPDo8qSe@KChjHFoeKAuVD//w).

```python
      ₆      #  Push 36
       1š    #  Convert it to a list of digits, and prepend 1
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `ƵZ` is `136`.

Comment: There is a 11-byter that uses a single filter. `ƵZ` might be a hint ;)

Comment: @ovs Smart! Thanks for the hint. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 50 bytes

```
520$*¶

00$.`
.+(...)
$1
G`0
A`[3-5].*[3-5]|[6-9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy9TIQEXr0DYuLgMDFb0ELj1tDT09PU0uFUMu9wQDLseEaGNd01g9LTBVE22maxn7P8aJS/c/AA) Link includes footer that prettifies the output. Explanation:

```
520$*¶

00$.`
.+(...)
$1
```

List all the integers from `0` to `520` inclusive, padded to 3 digits.

```
G`0
```

Only keep those integers with at least one `0` digit.

```
A`[3-5].*[3-5]|[6-9]
```

Discard those with more than one digit greater than `2` or with a digit greater than `5`.

Comment: I was looking forward to a regex solution!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 75 bytes

```python
print([r for r in[(x//36,x//6%6,x%6)for x in range(216)]if[0,3]>sorted(r)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI7pIIS2/SKFIITMvWqNCX9/YTAdImqkCKVUzTZBUBVBKoSgxLz1Vw8jQTDM2My3aQMc41q44v6gkNUWjSDNW8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>161</s> <s>146</s> <s>141</s> 135 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
for u in product(*[range(6)]*3):
 i,j,k=u
 if 0not in u or i>2and j>2or j>2and k>2or k>2and i>2:1
 else:print(u)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcsxDsMgDIXhnVN4DChDm0gdkJqLVBmiBlogsZFjhp6e0mZ7n/S//JE34VirZ9ohiGMh2g4IeyYWozwxFAgImWktT@nMgxd8ue6mZzNqqyD0sU/30oaHC5L84gLtFqZhwRXiNDTEE@mPdKIF9qrAbYezmQNKV3StXw)

-5 thanks to [qwr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17360/qwr)

Comment: You can probably use itertools cartesian product and filter lambda to save some bytes over triple for loop

Comment: @qwr I don't know what is itertools, Can you upload a TIO link?

Comment: See Kevin Cruijssen's answer for an example

Comment: @qwr Thanks, -5 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
ΦＥφ﹪%03dι∧№ι0∧›6⌈ι›²ΣＥι‹2λ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEER/JSwIG1ghVvDiSQS9GBD8gqUJuJA2kjbi38et1DnOvDf9k0ufObV2LzLOeJE0x4KeX7hzzpHxOdSUETZuH4CMWEvmNAY856q4kAEHa3UtkRcZDgp6/shQB/wJ/6Uj89BueVfzFqcJoVM42TXH1tr2nb4) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  φ                         Predefined variable `1000`
 Ｅ                          Map over implicit range
        ι                   Current value
   ﹪%03d                    Formatted to 3 0-filled digits
Φ                           Filtered where
           ι                Current value
          №                 Contains
            0               Literal string `0`
         ∧                  Logical And
               6            Literal string `6`
              ›             Is greater than
                 ι          Current value
                ⌈           Maximum character
             ∧              Logical And
                   ²        Literal integer `2`
                  ›         Is greater than
                      ι     Current value
                     Ｅ      Map over digits
                        2   Literal string `2`
                       ‹    Is less than
                         λ  Current digit
                    Σ       Take the sum
                            Implicitly print
```

28 bytes for the prettier version:

```
ΦＥφ⪫﹪%03dι-∧№ι0∧›6⌈ι›²ΣＥι‹2λ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3RCsIwDEV/pQSEFDqoE3zxSQQFWUHwC8paMNC1o1tlf19TmHkJnHtPMn5sHpMNtb4yxRXvFFaf0dgZj1prJZ6JIprkSkgIB31yoARJJaADyesaHd5SYZOYadjRI3vb7sCZ68ZuNJUJqQn/pFfizaw9YnPwy4LQcznIfS611u4bfg) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 62 bytes

```ruby
p (z=*0..5).product(z,z).select{|x|x.min<1&&(x-[3,4,5])[1]}|[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBo8pWy0BPz1RTr6AoP6U0uUSjSqdKU684NSc1uaS6pqKmQi83M8/GUE1No0I32ljHRMc0VjPaMLa2Jjr2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 106 bytes

```rs
for i in 0..6{for j in 0..6{for k in 0..6{let mut t=[i,j,k];t.sort();if t<[0,3,6]{print!("{i}{j}{k}
")}}}}
```

Actually using nested loops is barely shorter than my attempt using itertoools.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMHqtDyF3MTMPA1NheqlpSVpuhY3s9LyixQyFTLzFAz09MyqQbwsFF42nJeTWqKQW1qiUGIbnamTpZMda12iV5xfVKKhaZ2ZplBiE22gY6xjFltdUJSZV6KooVSdWVudVVudXculpFkLBBAbF0LpBQsgNAA)

Comment: `if[0,3,6]>t` saves 1 byte

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
f>,Z3ST^U6 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P81OJ8o4OCQu1EzB@P9/AA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249354/65425)

```
f>,Z3ST^U6 3
        U6    Range up to 6 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
       ^   3  Cartesian product with itself 3 times = [0,1,2,3,4,5] * [0,1,2,3,4,5] * [0,1,2,3,4,5]
f             Filter for elements T such that:
 >,Z3ST       [0,3] > sorted(T)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-a`, <s>73</s> 64 bytes

```
[345]([12]0|0[012])|[12]([1-5]0|0[0-5])|0([012][0-5]|[345][012])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdVm0km6iUuyCpaUlaboWNx2ijU1MYzWiDY1iDWoMog2AtGYNiAcU0jWFiAFpzRoDDbAkmFcD1gRRDDEHatwCKA0A)

Surprised nopony did this yet. Probably golfable!

EDIT: -9 thanks to [math junkie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65425/math-junkie) for reminding me of the shorter output format. Now it's 1 byte per combination :P I still think it can be golfed further, possibly with a new approach :-)c

Comment: I think you can drop the `-` separators since that's allowed by the challenge rules

Comment: @mathjunkie omg i forgot thank u

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
6p3’Ż€Œ!€ẎQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@swPhRw8yjux81rTk6SRFIPtzVF/j/PwA)

A niladic link that returns the 64 triples. This is [my answer to the follow-up question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268857/42248) but with the sorting code removed.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 271 bytes

```
@!! 2>nul||cmd/q/v/c%0&&exit/b&for /l %%i in (0,1,5)do @(for /l %%j in (0,1,5)do @(for /l %%k in (0,1,5)do @(set s=%%i%%j%%k&set p=!s:0=!&if !p:~!==~ set p=0
if !p!. neq !s!. set/af=!p!/10&set/al=!p!%%10&if !f! lss !l! (if !f! leq 2 echo !s!)else if !l! leq 2 echo !s!)))
```